# move_base - missed desired rate

Tags: navigation, move-base, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a quite high level question. I'm currently trying to unplug the amcl node from the navigation stack and substitute it with a custom localization algorithm. Although I'm able to broadcast the transformation /map -> /odom with a high frequency (40Hz), I'm getting lots of errors such as

```
[ WARN] [1422360986.992858074, 13.073000000]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 10.0000Hz... the loop actually  took 0.8180 seconds

[ WARN] [1422360986.993048443, 13.073000000]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 5.0000Hz... the loop actually  took 0.7770 seconds
```

as well as

```
[ERROR] [1422360988.321754058, 14.389000000]: Extrapolation Error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 13.881000000 but the latest data is at time 13.871000000, when looking up transform from frame [map] to frame [odom]
```

I was wondering what can cause such an error. The parameters in move_base are set so that the /amcl is not popping any of those warnings/errors.

Thanks and regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201838/move_base---missed-desired-rate/) by [Federico](https://answers.ros.org/users/18920/federico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2015-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first errors come from the code taking longer to run than expected. It should be independent of the tf source.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Federico](https://answers.ros.org/users/18920/federico/) on 2015-02-03**:
Thanks David. Actually the update rate was too slow